# Getting widget/item ids within TabbedPanel

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have created a simple App in Kivy that has tabs and within each tab I only have a few widgets. Prior to adding the tabbedPanel I had no issue reaching each widget through "ids". For example:

```
app.root.ids.mylabel1.ids.mylabel2.content
```

However, now that I have added widgets within the tabbedPanel they become unreachable for me. The tabbedPanel "blocks" me and contains no ids: For example my .kv-file has a button:

```
<SelectableButton>:
    text: self.button_text
    id: SelectableButton_id
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1) if self.selected else (0, 0.517, 0.705, 1)
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    state: self.btnState
    on_release:
        print(app.root.content.ids)
```

returns an empty dict. I followed the guidance for tabbedPanel and found that it only has one "children" which is ".content". But still I am not able to reach any widgets within this tab.

Am I going about this the wrong way? Or can anyone guide me to how to access the widgets within a certain tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Kivy TabbedPanel, you can reference the `ids` using `app.root.ids.id-name` or `self.ids.id-name` e.g. `app.root.ids.label3.text` or `self.ids.label3.text` because when your kv file is parsed, kivy collects all the widgets tagged with *id’s* and places them in this `self.ids` dictionary type property.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    size_hint: .5, .5
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'first tab'
        Label:
            text: 'First tab content area'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: tab2
        text: 'tab2'

        BoxLayout:
            id: box1
            orientation: 'vertical'

            Label:
                id: label1
                text: 'Second tab content area'
            Button:
                id: button1
                text: 'Button that does nothing'

            BoxLayout:
                id: box2
                orientation: 'vertical'

                Label:
                    id: label2
                    text: 'Label 2'

                BoxLayout:
                    id: box3
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    Button:
                        id: button2
                        text: 'Button 2'
                    Label:
                        id: label3
                        text: 'Label 3'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'tab3'
        RstDocument:
            text:
                '\\n'.join(("Hello world", "-----------",
                "You are in the third tab."))

""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Test, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(f"\nself.ids.items():")
        for key, val in self.ids.items():
            if isinstance(val, Label) or isinstance(val, Button):
                print(f"\tkey={key}, val={val}, val.text={val.text}")
            else:
                print(f"\n\tkey={key}, val={val}")

        print(f"\nself.ids.label3.text={self.ids.label3.text}")


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sadly, I quickly realised that my issue didn't have to do with the ids but the fact that I kept creating new class objects each time I try to call one of the classes. This is a broader problem I have. Ideally I would like to have class objects to be created upon starting the app. After which I call these class objects as a "global variable" in that module. It's my first time creating a small app hence the confusion. I guess the questions should be "how do I create one single class object of each class and then use that object for all desired activities in that class.

Comment: Please provide minimal code including TabbedPanel and steps to recreate the problem(s).

Comment: I solved it and I almost would like to delete this post since it had nothing to do with the actual problem. But thanks for your engagement it did help me find the problem which was that I was creating new class objects several times because I didn't where to initiate my classes. My solution was to create class objects under build() ass Objectproperties. For example: self.class_object1 = my_custom_class() was defined within the build method. Hence the self.class_object1 is accessible througout my App under App attributes.

Comment: If my answer have some how helped you in your project, please accept the answer. Thank you.